# How to invoke a batch script (customize merge) , when svn merge is invoked?

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, branch, svn-merge

When I try to merge the branch back to the trunk, a batch script must be invoked which runs sonar analysis. If the analysis is successful, only  then the merge should proceed further, else it must be aborted. i.e. on clicking merge, an analysis must be run in the background.

The same can be achieved during the commit process, by creating a pre-commit hook script. But, is it possible to do something like this for merge process also? If so, please guide me further.

Answer (score 1):

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html

Please go through the mentioned link. It should help you on this topic of merging and hooks.